# sum of the reciprocal fourth powers of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

How do I find $x_1^{-4}+x_2^{-4}+x_3^{-4}$ knowing that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are roots of the polinomial $f=X^3-3X^2+1$. I tried with $X^4=3X^3-X$ but I dont know what to do next.

Comment: It would help us, if you explained whether you know about Vieta relations. This is a bit taxing an exercise if you have not heard about them at all, but ... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1=3X^2-X^3\\X^{-2}=3-X\\X^{-4}=(3-X)^2$$

Comment: Simpler than what I suggested!

Answer (score 3):

Because
$$f(X)=(X-x_1)(X-x_2)(X-x_3)=X^3-3X^2+1$$
expanding and equating the coefficients of like powers gives
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3=3,\quad x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3=0,\quad x_1x_2x_3=-1.\qquad(*)
$$
(Look up Vieta relations for this and more).

Also, dividing $f(x_i)=0$ by $x_i^4$ gives, for all $i=1,2,3$
$$
0=\frac{f(x_i)}{x_i^4}=\frac1{x_i}-\frac3{x_i^2}+\frac1{x_i^4}.
$$
Therefore
$$
I_4:=x_1^{-4}+x_2^{-4}+x_3^{-4}=3\left(x_1^{-2}+x_2^{-2}+x_3^{-2}\right)-
\left(x_1^{-1}+x_2^{-1}+x_3^{-1}\right).
$$
The game we play here is to user the relations $(*)$ to evaluate these sums.
Because the sums can be written in terms of polynomials that are symmetric in the $x_i$s we can do this easily (with a little experience).

Let us first consider the sum
$$
I_1=\left(x_1^{-1}+x_2^{-1}+x_3^{-1}\right).
$$
By bringing the terms on the r.h.s. together to have a common denominator we get
$$
I_1=\frac{x_2x_3+x_1x_3+x_1x_2}{x_1x_2x_3},
$$
but the relations $(*)$ imply that this fraction is equal to zero.

We also need
$$
I_2=\left(x_1^{-2}+x_2^{-2}+x_3^{-2}\right).
$$
Here we see by expanding $I_1^2$ that
$$
0=I_1^2=I_2+2\left(\frac1{x_1x_2}+\frac1{x_1x_3}+\frac1{x_2x_3}\right).
$$
Similarly using a common denominator we get
$$
I_{1,2}:=\left(\frac1{x_1x_2}+\frac1{x_1x_3}+\frac1{x_2x_3}\right)=\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{x_1x_2x_3}=-3.
$$
Putting all this together gives 
$$
I_4=-6I_{1,2}=18.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of $x^3-3x^2+1$ then $\zeta_1=x_1^{-1},\zeta_2=x_2^{-1},\zeta_3=x_3^{-1}$ are the roots of $p(z)=z^3-3z+1$. By Viète's theorem $\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\zeta_3=0$ and $\zeta_1\zeta_2+\zeta_1 \zeta_3+\zeta_2 \zeta_3 = -3$, hence $\zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2+\zeta_3^2=6$. We have $\zeta_k^3 = 3\zeta_k-1$ hence $\zeta_k^4 = 3\zeta_k^2-\zeta_k$ and

$$ \zeta_1^4+\zeta_2^4+\zeta_3^4 = 3(\zeta_1^2+\zeta_2^2+\zeta_3^2)-(\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\zeta_3) = \color{red}{18}.$$